# Should we have a migration path to M&TV.SE now that it has graduated?

Tags: feature-request, closing-questions, migration

<del>According to [a comment by a mod](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3691/when-does-a-movie-question-get-migrated-to-movies-and-tv#comment-11562), the *Movies & TV* stack is about to graduate. This is [confirmed by a mod on M&TV.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1268/9382).</del>

[*Movies & TV* has graduated!](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/9382)

Since there has been some manual migration to that stack already, do we want to add it to the list of migration paths when it graduates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [Data Explorer query,](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/173076/migrations-from-arqade-to-su) when run on Movies&TV, gives us a list of incoming migrations. It's not filtered only on migrations from SciFi, but 99% of them are, so I won't bother forking the query to allow filtering.

Results: From the beginning of 2014 there have been 14 migrations from here to M&TV. None of them have been rejected by the M&TV mods, although there were a bunch of rejected migrations back in 2013 - some as Duplicates, others as Unclear or Off-topic. But all in all, mostly unrejected.

I don't know if 14 successful migrations constitute a large enough sample to say that it should be added to migration paths, but I tend to think so, with one caveat: we need to be clearer about what doesn't fit *here* and should move to M&TV.

[This discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3691/when-does-a-movie-question-get-migrated-to-movies-and-tv) the other day shows that some people, including high-rep users, aren't entirely on the same page regarding what should be migrated. It's clear that non-SF&F movies or shows should go. It's pretty well established, I think, that asking about a non-genre show or movie is *probably* fine if the question related to a genre-ish element within that movie, but having a bit of genre-ish content doesn't make a show SF&F automatically. But what that discussion seem to indicate is that non-genre questions are off-topic, even if they're in an explicitly on-topic show.

This, I think, is unclear to all. Is this the consensus opinion? Where exactly is the line drawn about non-SF&F elements in SF&F works?

Once we've established that, I think the migration path should be added.

Comment: You make a good point, and I'd like to argue that having a migration path is _better_, because that will effectively put it to a vote, where it's otherwise left to the opinion of a single moderator.

Comment: @SQB Not necessarily. Even with a migration path, a single moderator can still migrate without there being a vote.  Additionally, once auto-migrated, it becomes difficult to get the question back. Given the number of marginal questions I've seen closed, then reopened, all without moderator intervention, I have ... Concerns... About auto-migration without a clear need.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

It should be added to the list of migration paths. That way, a possible migration is put to the vote, rather than left to the opinion of a single moderator.

(Vote up if you agree, down if you disagree).

Comment: Please add some reasons why.

Answer (score 4):

Over the course of 2014, there were about 2 migrations a month.  We mods can handle that low workload of manually migrating questions.

The community as is does not have a solid consensus of when questions that overlap in topic between us and another site should be migrated.  In the past week, I've declined 2-3 flags where someone saw a [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) question and wanted it moved to Arquade, even though they're lore questions about sci-fi/fantasy games.  These are questions that are clearly on topic for us.

There's a steady stream of flags and comments that try to get behind-the-scenes questions about sci-fi/fantasy films and TV shows migrated to Movies & TV.SE.  These are on topic here, and we've got plenty of this type of question.  There's a handful of questions that get posted here that are either about films or TV shows that aren't sci-fi/fantasy, or are about sci-fi/fantasy films or TV shows that are digging pretty deep into non-sci-fi/fantasy elements.  These get migrated, and usually not rejected.

Things are fine as-is, we don't need a migration path.  A migration path complicates the process, as whenever there's disagreement (and there's *plenty* of disagreement on migrations, search Meta), it's nigh impossible to undo.  When a migration happens, we're kicking the question out of our court, so we lose control over it.  I'd prefer that ability stays in the hands of moderators, who are more familiar with the fine details of what should and shouldn't be migrated.