# Can we have a migration path from our meta to SE meta?

Tags: feature-request, meta, migration

The OP of the following question wanted it to be migrated to general meta:
[The questions page gets weird when there's more than 500 questions with new activity](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10701/19561)

I could only flag for moderator; there is no migration path to meta.SE. It seems like a logical migration path for any meta.

There are probably more questions here that are not specific to this Stack but are general issues.

**Can we have a migration path from meta.scifi.se to meta.se?**

Comment: Pretty soon, that'll mean chopping off 'scifi' from the beginning of the URL :P

Answer (score 2):

### Meh.

We've only migrated [three questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) from here to main meta in the last year. That's a small enough workload for five moderators to handle easily. As Kevin [said](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8161/migration-to-mtv-reopening-the-discussion#comment24343_9173), **the primary reason for a migration path is that the volume of migrations becomes a strain on mods' time.**

As to the specific question you link to, **at no time did the OP say he wanted it migrated.** I mentioned the possibility in a comment, and he responded, "if you want to migrate to meta.SE (can you do that?) then feel free." I didn't particularly want to migrate it - in fact, I kind of like having that question here as a monument to [Operation Front Page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10691/31394) this weekend - so I left it alone. But now that you've flagged it, I'll wait for another mod to handle that flag, and perhaps it will get migrated after all.